# Can no longer login in Java application after entering wrong login

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I am having this issue with my code wherein when I try to enter a wrong login, I cannot login any more after entering the correct login. This is my method for the login authentication which connects to my database. So what's wrong here? Is it a JDBC mistake I made or in my actual Java code?

```
public void loginAuthentication(String getUsername, String getPassword) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    try {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        final String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:myDB;",
                dbUsername = "adminUsername",
                dbPassword = "myPassword";

        Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUsername, dbPassword);

        Statement queryStatement = dbConnection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM LOGIN_DETAILS WHERE USERNAME='" + getUsername + "'";
        ResultSet rs = queryStatement.executeQuery(SQL);

        while (rs.next()) {

            userName = rs.getString("USERNAME");
            passWord = rs.getString("PASSWORD");

        }

        if ((userName == getUsername) && (passWord == getPassword)) {

            loginSuccess = true;

        } else {

            System.out.println("Invalid login");

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMessage);

    }

}
```

It works fine when I enter any valid login credentials on the first try.

UPDATE:
I am now using the .equals method and I can successfully login even entering wrong credentials. However, I still continue to get an error which is

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException".
```

Hope this helps you guys to figure out what is wrong with my code.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the full stack trace of the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at AppData.Login.loginAuthentication(Login.java:69)
at AppGUI.StartUIComponents$1.actionPerformed(StartUIComponents.java:105)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: don't usee == to check the strings . use equals method

Comment: I just did that. I am currently using the .equals method. I login now but I still get an error when I try entering wrong credentials.

Comment: what's the full stacktrace? NullPointerException doesn't help much

Comment: And which line is line 69 of login.java ?

Comment: Double check that your login to the database is working right now. Just use some other tool and try to login to the database.

Comment: The database works fine, Alex. I'm able to connect using NetBeans and Squirrel SQL.

Comment: Line 69 is the if statement for the login

Comment: @jtothebee .Is you problem solved now?

Comment: Whereas you must mention **line 69**